# AnyLogic: how to get 2nd or 3rd nearest agents?

Tags: anylogic, agent

In agent based model, let say I have 10 locations and in each location I have random number of people(10~20). Also, I have 5 facility locations. Now I can send all people from each people-location to nearest facility using getNearestAgent(). But I want to send 70% people to nearest one, 20% to second nearest one and 10% to 3rd nearest facility. How can I do that?

I put all locations in GIS map. And successfully send people to nearest facility.

[Actual implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t701K.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a function that takes as argument the person and returns a location:

```
Location nearest=person.getNearestAgent(locations);
 if(randomTrue(0.7)){
      return nearest;
 }else{
      
      List <Location> otherLocations=findAll(locations,l->!l.equals(nearest));
      Location secondNearest=person.getNearestAgent(otherLocations);
      if(randomTrue(2.0/3.0){
            return secondNearest;
      }else{
           List <Location> otherLocations2=findAll(otherLocations,l->!l.equals(secondNearest));
           return person.getNearestAgent(otherLocations2);
      }

 }
```

Comment: Felipe - thank you so much. For me, Person (in main - people) is agent and locations of them are based exported data (lat&log). At each location, multiple people. Getting error in first line of code. I tried: Person nearest = people.getNearestAgent(pharmas);. Error says:  The method getNearestAgent(Main._pharmas_Population) is undefined for the type Main._people_Population. I should create this function in main, right?

Comment: if you are using people.getNearestAgent you are not using my code, so i can't help if you decide to do something completely different and ignore my sugggestion

Comment: Felipe - Sorry, I misunderstood. When I was getting error, I was trying with different combinations. Your codes were a great help. I really appreciate you. I did in the following way and it works now. Pharma nr = this.getNearestAgent(main.pharmas);

if (randomTrue(0.7)){
 return nr;
}else{
 List <Pharma> other = findAll(main.pharmas, l->!l.equals(nr));
 Pharma sec = this.getNearestAgent(other);
 if (randomTrue(0.1)){
  return sec;
 }else{
  List <Pharma> other2 = findAll(other, l->!l.equals(sec));
  return this.getNearestAgent(other2);
 }
}